# Error SQUASHFS?

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, boot

i'm having problems installing elementary os freya 32 bits, i have a really older laptop from a little cousin and want to install elementary, i'm using rufus to create the bootable usb and install it, but i'm stuck at elementary logo, and having some SQUASHFS errors, i have a hp laptop with elementary freya running just fine, but in this one nothing.

P.S. i know how to install linux based operative systems but still i'm not a linux daily user, so i'm not too familiar with troubleshooting methods or how to fix problems

Comment: Can you copy over the error you're getting? And what are the specs on the laptop?

Comment: This is the error ->Stopping CPU interrupts balancing daemon                                 [875.573563] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read fragment cache entry [c9d1cd2]                                                                                                                [875.574936] SQUASHFS error: unable to read page, clock c9d1cd2, size 3d1bc                                                                                                                              Don't know the specs since i haven't been able to boot any OS, but it's a Lenovo/IBM ThinkPad T60 @wolf

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that the image on your USB drive is not corrupted?

You can either use *Check disk for defects* in the boot menu and/or you can verify that you can boot from this medium (*Try without installing*) works on another computer.

[image: Check disc for defects]

(You might want to check https://elementary.io/docs/installation#verify-your-download as well)

Comment: I checked the image in my computer an it's fine.

Comment: Did you check it in the laptop you want to use it?

Comment: I didn't check it on the laptop sorry, as i said on top, i don't know how to, my knowledge of linux is really basic.

Comment: You have to touch a key while booting and select the item highlighted from the boot menu, cf. screenshot.